# In Owin is it possible to set multiple set-cookie headers

Tags: cookies, owin

It seems that OWIN uses "context.Response.Headers" as a IDictionary. This precludes returning multiple cookies ("Set-Cookie") for a request.
Is there a way around this silly limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ResponseCookieCollection.Append`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.responsecookiecollection.append(v=vs.111).aspx) method.

Example usage:

```
context.Response.Cookies.Append("cookie", "1");
context.Response.Cookies.Append("cookie", "2");
```

---

**Side note:**

From [section 4.1 of RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1):

> Servers SHOULD NOT include more than one Set-Cookie header field in
> the same response with the same cookie-name.  (See Section 5.2 for
> how user agents handle this case.)

Hence multiple `Set-Cookie` headers with the same key (as in example above) are not recommended, but not forbidden.